# C++: Function to handle different size arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I have 2 2D arrays that represent a maze

`const char maze1[10][11]`
and
`const char maze2[20][21]`

I'm trying to create 1 function to handle both mazes like so:

```
void solveMaze(maze[][])
{
}
```

and just pass the maze like `solveMaze(maze1);`
However, I have to supply a size for the array, which is different depending on which maze is being passed in. Without overloading the function or using function templates, how can I have 1 function to handle both arrays?

Comment: If you're writing C++, is there any particular reason you're not using STL containers?

Comment: not familiar with STL, I'm still a beginner

Comment: Also, aren't these **2D** arrays?

Comment: I'm going to dispute the claim that you have two *3D* arrays. Those look rather two-dimensional to me. And the answer is: you can't. You either need to pass in xMax and yMax as well or use STL containers (which is what you should be using)

Comment: Could you link me to what STL containers are? I've never heard of them

Comment: @dukevin - see Brendan's answer below. A `vector` is one example which would be perfect here. EDIT: Also; http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## C++ answer

Use [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/):

```
// Initialize the vector with 11 rows of 10 characters
std::vector<std::vector<char> > maze(11, std::vector<char>(10));

void solveMaze(const std::vector<std::vector<char> > &maze) {
    // note that you can access an element as maze[x][y]
}
```

The [`boost::multi_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html) is slightly more efficient (if you're allowed to use boost). I think it goes something like this:

```
boost::multi_array<char, 2> maze(boost::extents[10][11]);

void solveMaze(const boost::multi_array<char, 2> &maze) {
    // note that you can access an element as maze[x][y]
}
```

## C answer

Use pointers:

```
const char maze1[10][11];

void solveMaze(char *maze, size_t x_length, size_t y_length) {
    // note that you can access an element as maze[x + (x_length * y)]
}
```

Comment: Your C example is way wrong. A 2D array in C is NOT an array of pointers.

Comment: @Dave - Right, sorry. I don't do C enough. It's fixed now.

Comment: For the C++ version, you should probably pass either a reference or a const reference to the std::vector.  Otherwise, there will be an unnecessary (and perhaps incorrect) copy of the container.

Answer (score 1):

Std c++ doesn't allow variably sized arrays. Gnu extensions allow this.

given a gnu compiler, you can

```
 void solvemaze(int w, int h, const char maze[h][w])
 {    //solve it...
 }
```

otherwise,

```
 void solvemaze(int w, int h, const char *maze)
 {    //solve it, bearing in mind:
      //maze[y][x] = maze[(w*y)+x];
 }
```

Comment: that gnu compiler answer looks really nice. if only i had gnu :(

Answer (score 1):

Actually it can be solved without vector:

```
template<size_t N, size_t M>
void foo(char (&maze)[N][M])
{
    // do your stuff here
}
```

On the other hand, I would also prefer to use vectors: it just feels safer.